# Disable Scroll Viewer on Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have a scroll viewer over my tab control e.g.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <TabControl>
        <!-- my tabs -->
```

However in one of the tabs there is a list view and I was wondering if there is a way to disable / turn off the scroll viewer just for this tab?

Comment: You could use a binding between the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and the `TabControl.TabControl.SelectedTab` properties. Apply a converter that disables the scroll bar when the current tab is the tab containing the list view.

Comment: This works, thank you very much - if you want to move that to an answer I will gladly mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a binding between the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and the `TabControl.SelectedTab` properties. Then apply a converter that disables the scroll bar of the `ScrollViewer` when the current tab is the tab containing the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the ScrollViewer outside of the TabControl? You could set the ScrollViewer in each pane you need it. Advantage: you only have a ScrollViewer where you want it and you don't scroll the complete TabControl and you always will see the headers.

Comment: Indeed but as the system I am working on has already been set up like this and there are 100s of tabs throughout - it's not perfect - but this is the only case where it is not needed.

Comment: Ok, just an idea. Then I would prefer Herdos answer ;)